# running 2 equivalent pieces of Python 3.7.6 code using the PIL library in a Jupyter notebook BUT getting different results

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library, jupyter

I am running 2 Python 3.7.6 scripts that rely on the PIL library in a Jupyter notebook and getting different results and I cannot determine why.  I believe the two pieces should be equivalent and the output identical.  Can someone tell me why the second block is not generating the same output as the first?

In essence, the code should do the same thing, split an image into its RGB color channels, multiply each channel by one of 3 different intensities, and then merge the channels back into a composite image.  Here is the source image:

[image: original image]

The only difference between the two code blocks is that in one I do the split within the innermost for loop and in the other, I do the split outside the for loops, copy the result to a variable and then assign the copy within the innermost loop.

In the first section I call the image split function within the innermost loop in the first segment and assign it to an image tuple variable:

`img_tmp = image.split()`

in the second, I call it outside the outer loop and assign it to an image tuple variable, and then assign that variable to a second variable within the innermost loop to reset the value every time through.

```
source = image.split()
...
for ...:
    for ...:
        img_tmp = source
```

---

1st code block (working correctly):

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw

# read image and convert to RGB
image=Image.open("readonly/msi_recruitment.gif")
image=image.convert('RGB')

# read True Type font
fnt=ImageFont.truetype("readonly/fanwood-webfont.ttf", size=50)

# source = image.split()

# initialize key constants and variables
R,G,B = 0,1,2
intensity = [0.1, 0.5, 0.9]
images = []
images_meta = []
banner_height = 70
banner_margin = 10
txt_color = 'rgb(255,255,255)' # white

# build a list of 9 images, 3 for each color channel with the appropriate color intensity
for channel in [R,G,B]:

    # multiply each channel by appropriate color intensity factor
    for i_factor in intensity:
#       img_tmp = source # split the original image into 3 separate channels (images) with 1 for each color
        img_tmp = image.split()
        img_band = img_tmp[channel].point(lambda x: x*i_factor) # multiply the channel color by the intensity factor
        img_tmp[channel].paste(img_band) # replace the selected channel image with its color corrected version
        img_out = Image.merge(image.mode, img_tmp) #  merge all 3 channels back into one image
        images.append(img_out)  # add the updated image to the list
        images_meta.append('channel {} intensity {}'.format(channel, i_factor))  # update the metadata

# create a contact sheet of 3 rows with one row per color channel displaying 
# an image with 3 different color intensities

first_image=images[0]
contact_sheet=PIL.Image.new(first_image.mode, (first_image.width*3,first_image.height*3 + banner_height*3))
x=0
y=0

# initialize the drawing context with the contact sheet as background
banner = ImageDraw.Draw(contact_sheet)

for i,img in enumerate(images):

    # Lets paste the current image into the contact sheet
    contact_sheet.paste(img, (x, y) )

    # now draw the text and create a banner below the corresponding image
    banner.text((x, y + first_image.height + banner_margin), images_meta[i], font=fnt, fill=txt_color)

    # Now we update our X position. If it is going to be the width of the image, then we set it to 0
    # and update Y as well to point to the next "line" of the contact sheet.
    if x+first_image.width == contact_sheet.width:
        x=0
        y=y+first_image.height + banner_height
    else:
        x=x+first_image.width

# resize and display the contact sheet
contact_sheet = contact_sheet.resize((int(contact_sheet.width/2),int(contact_sheet.height/2) ))
display(contact_sheet)

contact_sheet.save('assignment_1.pdf')
```

resulting picture:

[image: image processed correctly]

---

2nd code block (runs, but does not process the image correctly):

````
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw

# read image and convert to RGB
image=Image.open("readonly/msi_recruitment.gif")
image=image.convert('RGB')

# read True Type font
fnt=ImageFont.truetype("readonly/fanwood-webfont.ttf", size=50)

source = image.split()

# initialize key constants and variables
R,G,B = 0,1,2
intensity = [0.1, 0.5, 0.9]
images = []
images_meta = []
banner_height = 70
banner_margin = 10
txt_color = 'rgb(255,255,255)' # white

# build a list of 9 images, 3 for each color channel with the appropriate color intensity
for channel in [R,G,B]:

    # multiply each channel by appropriate color intensity factor
    for i_factor in intensity:
        img_tmp = source # split the original image into 3 separate channels (images) with 1 for each color
        img_band = img_tmp[channel].point(lambda x: x*i_factor) # multiply the channel color by the intensity factor
        img_tmp[channel].paste(img_band) # replace the selected channel image with its color corrected version
        img_out = Image.merge(image.mode, img_tmp) #  merge all 3 channels back into one image
        images.append(img_out)  # add the updated image to the list
        images_meta.append('channel {} intensity {}'.format(channel, i_factor))  # update the metadata

# create a contact sheet of 3 rows with one row per color channel displaying 
# an image with 3 different color intensities

first_image=images[0]
contact_sheet=PIL.Image.new(first_image.mode, (first_image.width*3,first_image.height*3 + banner_height*3))
x=0
y=0

# initialize the drawing context with the contact sheet as background
banner = ImageDraw.Draw(contact_sheet)

for i,img in enumerate(images):

    # Lets paste the current image into the contact sheet
    contact_sheet.paste(img, (x, y) )

    # now draw the text and create a banner below the corresponding image
    banner.text((x, y + first_image.height + banner_margin), images_meta[i], font=fnt, fill=txt_color)

    # Now we update our X position. If it is going to be the width of the image, then we set it to 0
    # and update Y as well to point to the next "line" of the contact sheet.
    if x+first_image.width == contact_sheet.width:
        x=0
        y=y+first_image.height + banner_height
    else:
        x=x+first_image.width

# resize and display the contact sheet
contact_sheet = contact_sheet.resize((int(contact_sheet.width/2),int(contact_sheet.height/2) ))
display(contact_sheet)

contact_sheet.save('assignment_1.pdf')```
````

[image: image not processing correctly]

Comment: I will guess - when you assign `img_tmp = source` then Pythond doesn't create copy but only alias so when you change `img_tmp` then you also change `source`. So in next loop you work with modified version, not original. You may need `img_tmp = source.copy()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brifly: Python doesn't duplicate list/tuple when you assign to new variable.

---

In second version when you assign

```
 img_tmp = source
```

then Pythond doesn't create copy of data but only alias to original one. So when you change `img_tmp` then you also change `source` and in next loop you work with modified version, not original.

You need

```
 import copy

 img_tmp = copy.deepcopy(source)
```

or (because it is tuple with 3 arrays)

```
 img_tmp = (source[0].copy(), source[1].copy(), source[2].copy())
```

Comment: thank you!  I thought it might be due to aliasing but couldn't find any info that enabled me to confirm it and was left banging my head against the wall on that one.